# set::extract cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have an array in this structure:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [cd_bibliotem] => Array
            (
                [codiceBiblio] => 119179
                [codiceTematica] => 3106
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [cd_bibliotem] => Array
            (
                [codiceBiblio] => 119178
                [codiceTematica] => 3106
            )

    ) [...]
```

I want to have one array with all `codiceBiblio` values, I've tried this:

```
$t = Set::extract($t, '{n}.cd_bibliotem');
```

But I get:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [codiceBiblio] => 119179
        [codiceTematica] => 3106
    ) [...]
```

what's the right syntax to get just the codiceBiblio values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$t2 = Set::classicExtract($t,'{n}.cd_bibliotem.codiceBiblio')
```

alternatively:

```
$t2 = array(null);

foreach($t as $thing)
{
    $t2[] = $thing['cd_bibliotem']['codiceBiblio'];
}
```

Comment: $t2.append() is invalid PHP; Should be something like `$t2[] = $thing['cd_bibliotem']['codiceBiblio'];`

Comment: @thaJeztah edited for correctness.  I think I was thinking of array_push, but I guess that's unnecessary for one thing at a time.

Comment: almost there, there's still an error; you should remove the dot between the variable and the [] brackets. No problem for me, but in case an inexperienced PHP developer tries to use this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Only your arguments are wrong

> I want to have one array with all codiceBiblio values, I've tried this:
>
> $t = Set::extract($t, '{n}.cd_bibliotem');

The array path specified in the question points at an array - just change the path to point at a specific value, and you'll get a flat array as a return value:

```
$t = Set::extract($t, '{n}.cd_bibliotem.codiceBiblio');
```

Which will return:

```
array(
    119179,
    119178,
    ...
)
```

This is almost identical to the example for both [Set::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract) and [Hash::extract](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) (Hash replaces Set in 2.2, though both exist for backwards-compatibility) in the documentation.